# Find element by parent class and child text

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have web element shown below

[image]

need to click on element *'class = dxnb-gr'* and child have text "*Leave details*"

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='dxnb-gr']"
```

would give first element with given class.

```
//*[(contains(text()='Leave Details')]
```

would give child with particulate text

How could I combine those conditions?

Comment: Please highlight the Elements

Comment: Do you try this `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='dxnb-gr'] and contains(text()='Leave Details')]")`

Comment: Share the URL Pleasee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xpatH for `dxnb-gr` that has element wit specific text inside:

```
//*[@class='dxnb-gr'][.//*[contains(.,'Leave Details')]]
```

Comment: How do you implement for exact text ? "//*[@class ='dxnb-gr'][.text()='Leave Details'] did not worked.  in xml there are white spaces at the end dose it matters?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xpath:

```
.//li[@class='dxnb-gr' and descendant::*[contains(text(),'Leave Details')]]
```

[image: Get 'ul' which have a child with text 'Today']

Comment: Could you see the image I added? It is working for me.